# What is most secured and fast RDP client to connect from Apple Mac to Red Hat Linux Desktop?

Tags: macos, redhat, rdp

I am working for a big named client. They gave me a desktop with `Red Hat Linux` OS.I have installed RDP on my desktop. I use Mac Book at home.

I want to connect to my desktop at office from home.Right now I am using Real VNC to connect to my VNC server on my Linux box. But it is very slow and irritating. Can someone please suggest me RDP client which is highly secure and faster indeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For remote management to RDP servers from my MacBook Pro, I've been using the 2X RDP Client. It suites my needs well and has worked out great so far.

http://www.2x.com/rdp-client/windows-linux-mac/

Comment: I came across this. But i didn't try that. Is it secure and fast?

Comment: Yes, it is secure. The RDP protocol supports strong encryption and by default is encrypted. If you need additional security, try using RDP through a secure VPN tunnel. AND always use strong passwords.

As for speed; that depends on a number of outside factors, so it's difficult to provide you with a definitive answer. I can tell you that I have not had any speed issues using it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you install xrdp on the RHEL machine. Then install Microsoft RDP client (from the app store) on your Mac to connect to it.